# Class Not Found Error in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am a rookie PHP and MongoDB developer.

I have created a PHP web project with an HTML page that contains an 'Add' button. The name of the page is awards.html. The awards.html file contains its counterpart JavaScript file, awards.js. A code is executed in this js file when the Add button is clicked. This code sends an AJAX call to a PHP class elsewhere in the project named, example.php which contains code to execute a function called, clickFunction() in an Awards.php file, which returns a JSON array to the awards.html page.

The source code of my files is given as follows:

*Awards.html*

```
<div class = "divbottom">
    <div id="divAddAward">
        <button class="btn" onclick="onrequest();">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

*awards.js*

```
function onrequest() {
    $("#divAddAward").load('branding/dataaccess/example.php'); //The full path of the example.php file in the web root
    alert('Test');
    $.post(
            'branding/dataaccess/example.php'
            ).success(function(resp) {
        json = $.parseJSON(resp);
        alert(json);
    });
}
```

*example.php*

```
<?php

foreach (glob("App/branding/data/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}

$class = new Awards();
$method =  $class->clickFunction();
echo json_encode($method);
```

*Awards.php*

```
<?php

class Awards extends Mongo_db {

    //put your code here

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function clickFunction() {
        $array = array(
            'status' => '1'
        );
        return $array;
    }

}
```

The problem here is that the program is throwing me an error in example.php, Class 'Awards' not found, despite adding the `for` loop to include all the files. The Awards.php file is located in `App/branding/data/` path and example.php is located in `App/branding/dataaccess/` path.

Can anyone please tell me where exactly am I going wrong? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try manually including the file or see the list of included files to be sure it was included

Comment: have you include or require Awards.php?

Comment: together with the `include $filename;`, why don't you add `echo $filename."\n";` in your loop - maybe that makes it obvious what is going on. I suspect you want an absolute path - php can be funny about what it considers the starting point of relative paths.

Comment: Thank you Peace and Floris for replying. @ Peace: Yes I have tried using the include and require commands but it still doesn't work. @ Floris: What will inserting the echo command achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: as you said, example.php is located in App/branding/dataaccess/, so when you do your loop you're actually searching for files in App/branding/dataccess/App/branding/data which doesn't exist so nothing is included.

Try this:

```
foreach (glob("../data/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I tried your code but it still can't locate the file.

Comment: Okay my file was not located in the path specified in the foreach loop. It's working now! Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: Good! Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Update example.php to

```
<?php

foreach (glob('../data/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    //Echo out each included file to make sure it's included
    echo $filename . '<br />'; 
    include $filename;
}

$class = new Awards();
$method =  $class->clickFunction();
echo json_encode($method);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I tried your code but it still can't locate the file.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. try to use `spl_autoload_register();` to include or require all files at once on example.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once '../data/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Comment: @Razor i just edited the code, i just changed the path on the require_once try it and it should work now.

Comment: No sir. It's still now working. It gives the following error:  require_once(../data/Award.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\branding\data\Award.php

Comment: Okay I found the solution to the problem myself. The file was not located in the path specified in the foreach loop. So I think your previous code was correct. :)